# Iterate over Queryset backwards with Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to iterate over a queryset for a certain model and want to go over a table to another table. My models are the following (shrinked to a smaller version):

```
class Erp(models.Model):
    erp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    target_item = models.ForeignKey('Items', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='target_item')

class PE(models.Model):
    pe_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='pe_item')

class Items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
```

My Queryset looks like this where I am trying to loop through and want to print stuff for the class Erp:

```
pe_queryset = PE.objects.filter(item_id=2)
for pe in pe_queryset:
    print(pe.item.item_name) # is working
    print(pe.item.target_item.erp_id) # is not working
    print(pe.item.target_item) # gives back Erp.None
```

Is it possible to iterate through the entry to another tables Foreign Key like this or how could I accomplish to get the value from ERP with my Queryset?

I tried to iterate through every possible column name.

```
pe_queryset = PE.objects.filter(item_id=2)
for pe in pe_queryset:
    print(pe.item.item_name) # is working
    print(pe.item.target_item.erp_id) # is not working
    print(pe.item.target_item) # gives back Erp.None
```

Comment: pe.item.target_item is ModelManager, not Queryset. In order to  turn that into queryset you need to call .all() or .filter() method on it. Then you can iterate this queryset and for each instance of target item you will be able to get erp_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Erp` is not a single object instance like `item` so you should use its relationship as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to retrieve related data. Here is an example:

```py
pe_qs = PE.objects.filter(item_id=2)

for pe_obj in pe_qs:
    print(pe_obj.item.item_name)
    # You can use .values to obtain id's
    print(pe_obj.item.target_item.all().values('erp_id'))

    # Or Iterate directly
    erp_qs = pe_obj.item.target_item.all()
    for erp_obj in erp_qs:
        print(erp_obj.erp_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This was very helpful. I would have another question for this example. Is it possible to go through this Model pe_obj.item.target_item with filtering a column from PE? 

Like erp -> items -> pe
My approach was something like:
pe_obj.item.target_item.filter(target_item__item_id__pe_item_id__pe_id=1)

But this isn't working and I am only be able to get to target_item__item__item_id

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to go in the other way. Then it would be something like `erp_obj.target_item.pe_item.all()`